# Prioritizing window.load functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, preloader

Sorry if this is a noob question (I'm a JS noob). Im working on a website in which the homepage consists of a preloader and a slideshow.

I've managed to set up both the preloader and the slideshow. However, I've noticed that both of them are being loaded at the same time. I need to find a way to first load the preloader and once the preloading is done, then start the slideshow.

I'm using (window).load on both functions but I would like to know if there's a way to prioritize how things area loaded.

Here's my working code:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() { 

  jQuery('#wptime-plugin-preloader').delay(500).fadeOut("slow");

  setTimeout(wptime_plugin_remove_preloader, 3000);
  function wptime_plugin_remove_preloader() { 
  jQuery('#wptime-plugin-preloader').remove();
  }

});

jQuery(window).load(function() {

  $('#slideshow.royalSlider').royalSlider({
    arrowsNav: true,
    loop: true,
    keyboardNavEnabled: true,
    controlsInside: false,
    imageScaleMode: 'fill',
    arrowsNavAutoHide: false,
    autoScaleSlider: false, 
    numImagesToPreload: 0,
    transitionSpeed: 600,
    thumbsFitInViewport: false,
    navigateByClick: false,
    startSlideId: 0,
    transitionType:'fade',
    globalCaption: false,

  });

});
```

Regards,

Johann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine them both inside a single `jQuery(window).load`, and choose to run the royalSlider setup function inside the `wptime_plugin_remove_preloader` function, after removing the preloader:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() { 
  //set up the preloader
  jQuery('#wptime-plugin-preloader').delay(500).fadeOut("slow");

  setTimeout(wptime_plugin_remove_preloader, 3000);

  function wptime_plugin_remove_preloader() { 
      //Remove the preloader
      jQuery('#wptime-plugin-preloader').remove();

      //Set up the slider after removing the preloader
      $('#slideshow.royalSlider').royalSlider({
        arrowsNav: true,
        loop: true,
        keyboardNavEnabled: true,
        controlsInside: false,
        imageScaleMode: 'fill',
        arrowsNavAutoHide: false,
        autoScaleSlider: false, 
        numImagesToPreload: 0,
        transitionSpeed: 600,
        thumbsFitInViewport: false,
        navigateByClick: false,
        startSlideId: 0,
        transitionType:'fade',
        globalCaption: false,

      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't knew you could add a function inside another functions. This code this the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Activate the preloader on window.onload and call the slideshow function from inside the preload function (Note: Untested!):

```
jQuery(window).load(function() { 

  jQuery('#wptime-plugin-preloader').delay(500).fadeOut("slow");

  setTimeout(wptime_plugin_remove_preloader, 3000);
  function wptime_plugin_remove_preloader() { 
  jQuery('#wptime-plugin-preloader').remove();
  }
slideshow();
});

function slideshow() {

  $('#slideshow.royalSlider').royalSlider({
    arrowsNav: true,
    loop: true,
    keyboardNavEnabled: true,
    controlsInside: false,
    imageScaleMode: 'fill',
    arrowsNavAutoHide: false,
    autoScaleSlider: false, 
    numImagesToPreload: 0,
    transitionSpeed: 600,
    thumbsFitInViewport: false,
    navigateByClick: false,
    startSlideId: 0,
    transitionType:'fade',
    globalCaption: false,

  });

}
```

Comment: Your code as exact same behaviour as OP's one. You should call `slideshow` method from timeout callback. But in OP's code, this timeout seems useless. What should be done is to use the `fadeout` complete callback

Answer (score 0):

Put your the code that loads the slideshow inside

```
function wptime_plugin_remove_preloader() { 
      jQuery('#wptime-plugin-preloader').remove();
      //slideshow code here
  }
```

`$(window).load` would wait for the page to load all the elements, which you do need for your javascript to work, because you have to make sure the elements you are referencing in your code already exist in the DOM. To chain functions call each next function from the last block of the one preceeding